# SAP B1 query for stand alone documents

Tags: sql-server-2008, sapb1

I am trying to get this documents (sales orders) in SAP Business One, those that are not forwarded to Delivery or those that have no PO.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDR T0 INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.Docentry
WHERE T1.TrgtEntry IS NULL AND T1.BaseEntry IS NULL.
```

The problem is, we allow partial delivery of sales orders. So if sales order has 10 items and 5 of these items are partially delivered. This kind of documents are included in my query.

What can i do? I though this is easy but it's making me crazy. If only the header document can identify if it already have linking tables.

Thank you.

SAP B1 DB Schema

[image]

> ```
> **POR1 child table of purchase order (OPOR)
> **DLN1 child table of Delivery (ODLN)
> DocEntry is the relationship between Header(ORDR) and child(RDR1)
> BaseEntry is the relationship between child(POR1) to child(RDR1) 
> TrgtEntry is the relationship between child(RDR1) to child(DLN1)
> ```

Comment: Please show us some sample data.  Not everyone knows SAP database schemas.

Comment: Hi Tim, please see the update. Thanks. For the example above, this document does not have Purchase Order as the value of BaseEntry is Null, but 2 of it's items are forwarded to delivery. What i want is not to include this kind of transactions in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this, included the delivery lines table. See if it suits you.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDR T0 
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN DLN1 T2 ON T2.BaseEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE T1.TrgetEntry IS NULL AND T1.BaseEntry IS NULL AND T2.BaseEntry IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Kinyanjui Kamau. This solves my issue. (sigh)